# In PlantUML, how to put a label when using the class X extends Y syntax?

Tags: plantuml

I have a class diagram using this PlantUML syntax:

```
@startuml
class A
class B extends A
@enduml
```

How do I add a label for the arrow? My only constraint is that I cannot use the `<|--` syntax due to some other reasons. So I need to keep using this `extends` syntax...

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
@startuml
class A
class B extends A
class C

A -> C : label1
B -> C : label2
B --> A : label3
@enduml
```

[image]

Or just use note

```
@startuml
class A
class B extends A
class C

A -> C 
B -> C 
note left of A : Note 
@enduml
```

[image]